# HOWTO: Use reindent.py for dummies

Tags: python, indentation

I am a beginner at Python and have made the mistake of mixing spaces and tabs for indentations. I see people use `reindent.py`, but I have no idea how to use it. please explain in the simplest way possible without trying to use too fancy words and dumb it down as best as possible as I am a beginner.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

To install reindent with the python package manager, you can first run `pip install reindent` on your system. Then simply call from the terminal

```
reindent -n file.py
```

The script will modify `file.py`.

If you do not want to modify the original file, you can simply run the command without the `-n` flag, and you get:

```
reindent file.py
```

which will return a file called `file.py.bak`, which is the corrected version.

Comment: Please dumb it down a bit more, I am probably the stupidest person on the site right now. Sorry.

Comment: Correction(?):  On my system, `file.py.bak` is a backup of the original `file.py`, and the new `file.py` is reindented as desired.

Comment: this doesnt work for me as `reindent is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Answer (score 4):

You run `reindent.py` like this:

```
reindent.py <filename>.py
```

This will create `<filename>.py.bak` in the current directory.

If you prefer, you can run it like this: `reindent.py -n <filename>.py` if you don't want a backup file.

Comment: Do I run it in my desired file or add that line of code into reindent.py?

Comment: You use this in the shell. You are calling reindent.py as a program which converts your file into another file.

Comment: It tells me "invalid syntax" if I run it in a new shell.

Comment: Can you post the entire error? The SyntaxError might be coming from your PAYDAY.py file.

Comment: Define "entire error", sorry I am very new. The directory to my file is D:/PAYDAY.py/

Comment: If there is an error, there are 2 possible sources: PAYDAY.py or reindent.py. Since it is not clear where the SyntaxError is coming from, I wanted to look at the full error message. I suspect there is invalid syntax in PAYDAY.py. Can you get `python PAYDAY.py` to run without issues?

Comment: the "PAYDAY" is highlighted in red, and I also ran that line of code in a new python shell that would open if I opened Python IDLE.  I'm also using 2.7.8 IDLE to code and run my files.

Comment: Can you post your PAYDAY.py file?

Comment: The whole thing or just the part that is wrong? Because the whole thing will not fit.  while movePark != "r" and movePark != "f" and movePark != "time":    Error code is:"unindent does not match any outer identation level"

Comment: Let me suggest something else - can you download and install [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) and use this IDE to open your file? It should fix indentation for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse IDE, there are two formatting options available that can be used to accomplish this, accessed from the **Source** Menu. 
a) "**Source > Convert space-tabs to tabs**" or 
b) "**Source > Convert tabs to space-tabs**"
I was able to format code that had 2 spaces instead of a tab using the first option. You simply specify the  number of spaces to be converted into a tab.